# How to reuse Layers on AWS both locally using SAM and when they're deployed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

So far I have this `template.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  My Lambda for doing something

Resources:
  FirstLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: FirstLayer
      Description: First layer of dependencies
      ContentUri: layers/first-layer/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs14.x
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: nodejs14.x

  SecondLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: SecondLayer
      Description: Second layer of dependencies
      ContentUri: layers/second-layer/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs14.x
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: nodejs14.x

  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "MyLambda"
      Policies:
        - AmazonS3FullAccess
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Timeout: 30
      MemorySize: 2048 # Chrome will require higher memory
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Layers:
        - !Ref FirstLayer
        - !Ref SecondLayer
```

With this template I am able to start and invoke `MyLambda` locally and also deploy it to AWS. The problem I have is that I would like to reuse these same layers on other Lambdas as well, so for doing that I could simply extract these layers to another `yml` file, deploy them separately and then include the layers ARNs in the `Layers` property of my Lambda, but then, how can I run it locally with `sam`? I wouldn't like to have 2 `template.yml` files for my Lambda, one including the Layers on the `Resources` (like the one I already have) to run locally and another one with the refs to the actual layers ARNs to deploy on AWS, but that's the only solution I am seeing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question you need to ask is if those lambdas belong to the same application. If that´s not the case, you should use different templates, in order to deploy different stacks, to have isolated environments.

However, if you want to share resources, you have to very similar options:

1. Configure the layer in the parent template and pass the ARN as a parameter.

**template.yml**

```
Resources:
  SharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: shared_layer
      Description: Some code to share with the other lambda functions
      ContentUri: ./layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs14.x
      RetentionPolicy: Delete

  Application:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Application"
    Properties:
      Location: "./app.template.yml"
      Parameters:
        SharedLayer: !Ref SharedLayer
```

**app.template.yml**

```
Parameters:
  SharedLayer:
    Type: String
    Description: ARN of the SharedLayer
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: index.handler
      Layers:
        - !Ref SharedLayer
```

2. Configure the layers in a nested template, set the ARN as an output, and then pass its output as a parameter to the other templates.

**layers.template.yml**

```
Resources:
  SharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: shared_layer
      Description: Some code to share with the other lambda functions
      ContentUri: ./layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs14.x
      RetentionPolicy: Delete

Outputs:
  SharedLayerARN:
    Description: ARN of the Shared Layer
    Value: !Ref SharedLayer
```

**template.yml**

```
 Layer:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Application"
    Properties:
      Location: "./layers.template.yml"
  
 Application:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Application"
    Properties:
      Location: "./app.template.yml"
      Parameters:
        SharedLayer: !GetAtt Layer.Outputs.SharedLayerARN
```

Both scenarios are supported by AWS SAM.

Comment: Is it working with sam local start-api? I'm getting error: "samcli.commands.local.cli_common.user_exceptions.InvalidLayerVersionArn: SharedLayer is an Invalid Layer Arn"

Comment: Both scenarios don't work with sam local. The first option returns the same error as @MarcosOto pointed, The second option doesn't return any errors but you will get "Cannot find module" error when invoking the lambda function locally.